# Log4j2: Perform logger outputs

Tags: java, log4j2

I am using log4j2 (log4j version 2). All logger outputs are perfectly shown in the console (`<Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">`).

Additionally, is there an easy way to process these logger outputs, e.g., to assign them to a java string (e.g., for filtering them, sending a mail, ...)?

Answer (score 0):

Log4j2 provides built-in filters and an email appender. If you want to do custom processing you will probably need to write a custom filter or appender.

Comment: which filter exactly (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html)? it is unclear for me how it should work

Comment: do you have more suggestions for me?

Comment: I need more detail on what filtering you want to do before I can see if that could be accomplished with a built-in filter.

Comment: the logger output - which you can see in the console - should be send to a java String variable - so that i can perform that via a java application like a chat server

Comment: In that case you may be interested in the [SocketAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SocketAppender) that can send log messages to a remote machine?

Comment: simply into a variable is not possible? mh - tnx for answer - i will try it with SocketAppender

Comment: If you create a custom appender you can configure it and it will receive LogEvents. So it is possible but using existing appenders is easier...